# PHP data retrieval in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have one table having columns:

```
S.NO  month year  total
1     jan   2017  1000 
2     feb   2017  5000 
3     jan   2018  3000
```

I want to fetch data and arrange in such a way that total values of similar months are added and store in key value pair in array using PHP.
 There will be data only for years.
e.g.

2017 -> 6000
2018-> 3000 and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please refer to [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the table structure is like this,

[image: Sample Table]

The query should be

`SELECT SUM(tt),yr FROM t1 GROUP BY yr`

Sample output :
[image]

In PHP in the while loop just,
use something like,(just giving a sample, not the full thing)

`while($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
    $array[$row['yr']] = $row['SUM(tt)'];`

Comment: Thanks !! It works..
Its a simple but got stuck. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Please try -

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test1");
$newarray = array();
$i = 1; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    if($i==1){
        array_push($newarray, array("year"=>$row["year"], "total"=>$row["total"]));
    }else{
        $sr = array_search($row["year"], array_column($newarray, 'year'));
        if($sr === false){
            array_push($newarray, array("year"=>$row["year"], "total"=>$row["total"]));
        }else{
            $newarray[$sr]["total"]+=$row["total"];
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
print_r($newarray);
```